# RethinkDB update query runs very slow

Tags: node.js, promise, rethinkdb

In rethinkDB I required executing 10000 update query one by one with something unique data reference. It runs but it will take 25 to 30
minutes to perform on all 10000 records. I don't know what is an issue? Why query runs very slow?

```
let mergeDuplicateContactsInDB = (data) => {
 try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let arrPromise = [];
   let primaryRecordIden;
   if (data.arrMergeIdens.length > 0) {
    forEach(data.arrMergeIdens, (arrContactIdens, index) => {
     if (arrContactIdens.length > 0) {
      arrPromise.push(
       new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        primaryRecordIden = arrContactIdens[0];
        arrContactIdens.splice(0, 1);
        delete data.finalMergedData[index]['id'];
        arrDeletedIden = arrDeletedIden.concat(arrContactIdens);
        rdbdash.table("person")
        .filter({
         "id": primaryRecordIden
        })
        .update(data.finalMergedData[index])
        //.run(DBConfig.rConnection(), function (err, cursor) {
        .run()
        .then((result) => {
         if (!!result) {
          return resolve(true);
         }
        });

       })
      );
     }
    });
    Promise.all(arrPromise).then((data) => {
     resolve({
      "processed_data_length": data.length
     });
    });
   } else {
    resolve({
     "processed_data_length": 0
    });
   }
  });
 } catch (e) {
  throw new Error(e);
 }
};
```

Comment: guess the reason for the same is that you are first creating promises for the same and using promise .all to only move to the next step when all the data is finished processing . you should look at more on async way to process the data and wait for the callback ,this is keeping the process slow i guess

Comment: @RahulSingh if I do not put promise then sometime it may possible that it may be possible that data may update on wrong row

Comment: why is that so promise has nothing to do with updating to row more with asyc and sync . here using promise.all you are making the event loop wait untill all the rows have been updated and db operations are very costly and doing 10000 might take a reasonable amount of time

Comment: This is a code of merge contacts if I could not manage promise and run loop to execute all queries then if a user goes to list screen still it will not showing update contact listing because update query is processing. Hope you may understand my problem that why I should I put promise.

Comment: yes rahul that is exactly my point. I tried to use rethinkdb pooling but it may not helpful I think right now.

Comment: I told you if I did not put promise and async going to update, then i/o may be free and serve another request, but query updation is going on and if use going to the listing he will not receive updated merge list. This is query of merge duplicate contacts and if I do not run sync query then it will show duplicate contacts probably in listing. that is my worry.

Comment: i still donot get the point why are you using promises untill and unless you are planning to do something with that data in your app you dnt need to wait using .all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165020/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-rahul-singh).